# Read txt and logs on Elevated Batch Files

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Whenever I try to run a Batch File as an Administrator or as a Domain Admin, It doesn't load or read any external txt or log files and it is saying that it can't be found or the batch doesn't open at all.

```
del test.txt
```

Is there any way for the Elevated Batch to read or load txt and log files?

Note: The txt or log file is located in the same folder as the batch file.

Edited, thanks Matt!

Thank you!

Comment: Unless you show us what the code is actually doing I am going to assume you have it pointing to mapped drives or something. Being elevated does not affect the ability to read data.

Comment: I have edited the codeblock. The txt or log file is located in the same directory as the batch file. But whenever I run the Batch file as an administrator, it's not able to read the txt file. Thanks Matt!

Comment: When you elevate an executable, the default "start in" directory is automatically set to `%systemroot%\system32` and this cannot be changed (specifying a different "start in" directory is ignored). This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to overcome this is to start the body of the script with a statement to change the current directory to that of the batch file.

```
@Echo Off
CD /D "%~dp0"
If Exist "test.txt" Del "test.txt"
```

Or to provide the specific location of the file directly.

```
@Echo Off
If Exist "%~dp0test.txt" Del "%~dp0test.txt"
```

**`%0`** is a special variable which references the full path of the script itself. **`%~dp0`** expands to its drive and path, *which awkwardly ends with a trailing back slash*.